# How to construct json key contains dot

Tags: json, jsonbuilder

JsonBuilder
Script does not work when json key has dot. Works well when key does not contains dot.

```
security.set(data.getValue('set', index).toBoolean())
```

I want the output json like

```
"security.set": true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import data from <your json file path>;
```

`data['security.set']` will give you the value.